# Syntax Error. Open .exe with wine

Tags: wine, games, steam

So what i wanna do is load an .exe with wine.
Steam.exe, cause i wanna try to install windows game.

Its window location is **C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe**
See what i tried, and watch the learning process unfold.

Here comes Terminal screen with my tries...
Plz tell me how it should be.
And Tab works only on certain points or codes?
Did not do anything for me :´(

```
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$ wine C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\APB Reloaded\Launcher\APBLauncher.exe
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$ wine ¨C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\APB Reloaded\Launcher\APBLauncher.exe 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$ ^C
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$ wine ¨C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\APB Reloaded\Launcher\APBLauncher.exe 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$ wine ¨C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\APB Reloaded\Launcher\APBLauncher.exe¨
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$ wine C:\Program\ Files\(x86\)\Steam\Steam.exe 
wine: cannot find 'C:Program Files(x86)SteamSteam.exe'
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$ wine C:\Program Files\(x86\)\\Steam\Steam.exe
wine: cannot find 'C:Program'
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$ wine C:\Program\ Files\(x86\)\\Steam\Steam.exe
wine: cannot find 'C:Program Files(x86)\SteamSteam.exe'
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$ wine C:\\Program\ Files\(x86\)\\Steam\Steam.exe
wine: cannot find 'C:\Program Files(x86)\SteamSteam.exe'
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$ C:\\Program\ Files\(x86\)\\Steam\\Steam.exe
C:\Program Files(x86)\Steam\Steam.exe: command not found
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$ wine C:\\Program\ Files\(x86\)\\Steam\\Steam.exe
wine: cannot find 'C:\Program Files(x86)\Steam\Steam.exe'
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$ C:\Program Files(x86)\Steam\Steam.exe
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$ wine C:\\Program\ Files\(x86\)\\Steam\\Steam.exe
wine: cannot find 'C:\Program Files(x86)\Steam\Steam.exe'
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$ wine ¨C:\\Program\ Files\(x86\)\\Steam\\Steam.exe¨
wine: cannot find '�C:\Program Files(x86)\Steam\Steam.exe�'
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$ wine ¨C:\\Program\ Files\(x86\)\\Steam\\Steam.
wine: cannot find '�C:\Program Files(x86)\Steam\Steam.'
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$ wine ´C:\\Program\ Files\(x86\)\\Steam\\Steam.exe´
wine: cannot find '�C:\Program Files(x86)\Steam\Steam.exe�'
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$ wine ¨C://Program/ Files/(x86/)//Steam//Steam.exe¨
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$ ^C
chupacabra@kanker-desktop:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers aren't wrong but an easier way to mitigate special characters (like spaces and slashes) is to quote the whole string:

```
wine 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to to put the exe somewhere on your Ubuntu system (like the desktop) and run it from there by issuing following command in terminal

```
cd /home/DrugCrazedRebel/Desktop
wine Steam.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$ wine C:\\Program\ Files \(x86\)\\Steam\\Steam.exe`. You had it there, but you were missing a space between files and `\(x86\)`.